# Change charset of javascript generated document to utf8

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, character-encoding

In javascript I open a new window and then write content into its document:

```
var printerFriendlyWindow = window.open();
printerFriendlyWindow.document.open();
printerFriendlyWindow.document.write('Äpfel');
printerFriendlyWindow.document.close();
```

The generated document displays 'Äpfel' correctly, however when I print the page in the browser (Chrome), the german Umlaut Ä is replaced with A and 'Apfel' is displayed.

When I check the character format of the document, I get 'windows-1252':

```
alert(printerFriendlyWindow.document.characterSet);
// -> windows-1252
```

However, I need utf-8. Does anybody have an idea how I can change the document's character set? I already tried to insert a meta tag into the document but with no effect:

```
printerFriendlyWindow.document.write('<meta charset="utf-8">');
```

Any ideas how I could solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: @dandavis The funny thing is that the parent window's charset is 'UTF-8'.

Comment: hmmm. it might be the default of the browser/user/os, but opening a blank page url (with correct charset) and write()ing to that should fix it.

Comment: Okay, question is how can I open a blank page with the correct charset?

Comment: `<html><head><meta charset ...` as blank.html

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem only exists when I used Helvetica as the font in css. When I changed it to Arial it worked. So it must be something font-related...
Still strange that the browser displays it correctly but print-preview does not.